# How to sort an array while keeping the order of the index row matching the sorted row?

Tags: matlab, sorting

Easiest way is to show you through excel:

Unsorted:

[image: Need to sort second column while keeping the first one matching]

Sorted:

[image: Second column sorted, first column follows second column]

This example is with excel, but I would need to do the same thing in matlab with thousands of entries (with 2 rows if possible).

Here is my code so far:

```
%At are random numbers between 0 and 2, 6000 entries.

    [sorted]=sort(At);
    max=sorted(end);
    min=sorted(1);
%need the position of the min and max
```

But this is only 1 row that's being sorted and it has no numbers in the second row, and no index. How would I add one and keep it following my first row?

Thank you!

Comment: Per [the documentation for `sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) there is a second output of indices.

Comment: min and work the same way: [`[value, indx] = min(...)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html). The only thing in mind is that by default they operate on columns and not rows.

Comment: Thanks excaza... I missed it the first few times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to Matlab, but try

```
[sorted, I] = sort(At);
```

Where I will be a corresponding vector of indices of At. See the [Matlab Documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here. For the simple case where you just need the indices, the fourth form of `sort` listed in the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html#bup2pxc) already does this for you:

```
[sorted, indices] = sort(At);
```

In this case, `At(indices)` is the same as `sorted`.

If your "indices" are actually another distinct array, you can use [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
toSort = [At(:) some_other_array(:)];
sorted = sortrows(toSort);
```

In this case `sorted(:, 1)` will be the `sorted` array from the first example and `sorted(:, 2)` will be the other array sorted according to `At`.

`sortrows` accepts a second parameter which tells you the column to sort by. This can be a single column or a list of columns, like in Excel. It can also provide a second output argument, the indices, just like regular `sort`.